# c++ array value assignment time

Tags: c++, arrays, time

I am wondering how long it takes to allocate a value to an array in c ++.
I test a code which assign array arr = 0 and then, arr to change the value if arr> 20.

```
#include<iostream>
#include < windows.h >

using namespace std;

#define N 100000000
int arr[N] = { 0, };

int main(){
    int d;

    int *data;
    data = arr;

    double start = GetTickCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if (data[i] > 20){ //All data is zero
            // d = data[i];
            data[i] = 10;
        }
    }

    double end = GetTickCount();
    cout << (end - start) / (double)1000 << endl;

    return -1;
}
```

I think there is no data allocated to arr, 
because all the data is less than 20,
so the calculation time should be close to 0. but the calculation time is as 0.188s.
What is the reason?
enviroment: visual studio 2013 community
compile option(optimaztion): /O2(0.188s), /Ox(0.141)

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: @nwp I think he would need to turn them off, relative to the default.

Comment: @kabanus All compilers and IDEs I know default to optimizing for debugging, not for runtime performance.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/6phKFq - compiler is not as smart - it does not know that the array contains only zeros

Comment: @Alexander [Making the array local helps](https://godbolt.org/g/kjM7bX). Unfortunately [not on mscv](https://godbolt.org/g/uzeg9e).

Comment: @nwp not for all the compilers. clang still does not know.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on one point: the total time taken by assignment is 0 in your program. *But* the program does not reduce to assignments, it also contains tests (and at a lower level *jumps* to allow loops and conditionals). And here you ask for 100000000 tests...

Of course a normal human being can easily deduce that as the array was initialized to 0, and never modified, all the tests will return false and that the loop is just a no-op and could be optimized out. But unfortunately, that is too complex for most compilers, and IMHO most will just execute all the tests, which spends the observed duration.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is probably the raw time of iterating over the 100m array.

Theoretically, it may change if the compiler somehow deduces that the array is filled with zeroes, and, consequently, the `if` branch will never be executed. In this case, it may remove the loop.

I have not encountered such a smart compiler yet.

Comment: However, execute the code d = data [i] in the if statement, the operation time is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure would be to examine what code is output by the compiler, to determine what the compiler is doing with the loop (removing it entirely, replacing it with some simpler construct, emitting code for it "as is").

Most modern compilers are configured, by default, to NOT optimise for performance.   If you want such optimisations, you need to specifically enable it (IDE setting or compiler-specific command line option, depending on how you invoke the compiler).

Even with optimisation enabled, it is possible the compiler will not optimise the loop out of existence.  `GetTickCount()` is a library function and - particularly since `arr` is a global - the compiler may allow for the possibility that it affects the data stored in `arr` - which will mean it cannot not optimise the loop out of existence entirely.    Since it is a windows API function, compilers targeting windows might have "in-built" knowledge of what `GetTickCount()` does, but that is not guaranteed.   Without such in-built knowledge, the compiler would probably be less aggressive (or more conservative) with optimisation.

With aliasing in play (such as your case of having a pointer referencing the array) the compiler may also play it conservatively.

No matter what the compiler does, measured times will be affected by load on the host system (e.g. what other programs are consuming CPU cycles).